# SQLITE very slow Update using Transaction ,while INSERT is fast

Tags: performance, sqlite

I am using vb.net , sqlite dll . I have database with 100k records. I need to make simple update of one field value with new value based on single criteria. I need to make also 100K update command as below (using transaction)
      **UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET Matnum='yy' WHERE ordernumber=98739;**

When I run Update command , it takes too much time **~ 15 minutes**.  I tried to check Insert command performance as below (using Transaction), and added 100k row inserts:
        **"INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (Matnum) VALUES ('yyy');"**
it takes less than **3 seconds** !!

Why is this. what is wrong.
my code is as below

```
 Dim Str As String = ""
        Dim sCmdTmp As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(Str, SQLKonnLITE)
        Using trs As SQLiteTransaction = SQLKonnLITE.BeginTransaction()
            For x As Integer = 1 To 100000
                Str = "UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET Matnum='yy' WHERE ordernumber=98739;"
                  sCmdTmp.CommandText = Str
               sCmdTmp.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
            trs.Commit()
        End Using
```

Comment: Sorry, My code already contains it, but I missed into putting code to this post. I ried to remove Where and to Add WHERE , and all are the same. I have updated question with correct code

Comment: Why do you update the same row with the same value 100000 times?

Comment: Maybe no index on ordernumber?

Comment: I read that index slows update and insert. It only speed up SELECT. Right ?

Comment: No this is wrong. Indexes speed up operations that fetch rows. If you don't have an index on `ordernumber` create it.

Comment: how to create it. is it during table creation  , or before running update query

Comment: will there any update to my code after creating index to ordernum column ?

Comment: Execute: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_order_number ON TABLE_NAME (ordernumber);`. Remove UNIQUE if the column does not contain unique values. You can find more here: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-index/

Comment: Worked great... Thank you Mr Zach & forpas for support. I had flagged both of your commends are support to resolve the issue.  Thanks again..